# Concatenate two variables to obtain one

Tags: php, variables, concatenation

How to concatenate two variables to obtain something like this?

```
$var = "sss";
$i = 5;
${$var.$i} = "eeee"; // I know this is not correct, What should be here
echo $var5;
```

So here i need to obtain variables $var1  $var2  $var3  $var4 ... dynamically.

Comment: What are you trying to do? I mean what your "echo $var5;" line should print out?

Comment: Having such variable names often indicates bad design. Is there a reason why you can't use arrays?

Comment: I think you mean `echo $sss5;`

Comment: @Marco Demaio, @Leonid, No reason just didn't now why it's not working like this and the reason was that I have to echo $sss5 not $var5.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should consider using arrays instead, as those dynamic variables tend to only cause harm.

But basically what you do is syntactically correct, it should work.

```
${'var' . $i} = 'eeee'; // sets $var5
${$var . $i} = 'eeee'; // sets $sss5
```

Comment: Oh thanks , I was messing up some thing but your comments made thing clear.

Answer (score 3):

```
$i = 5;
$var[$i] = "eeee";
echo $var[$i];
```